# pyEZ : how to get junos default groups

Tags: junos-automation, juniper, pyez

I am working on a project to automate junos firewall policy creation workflow. I found pyEZ as the most viable option for my case.

Although I am able to retrieve the complete configuration from the device in xml format by using `rpc.get_config()` method. Unfortunately I don't see the default junos applications inside the retrieved xml file. But I can see them when running the commands manually on the device

> show configuration groups junos-defaults applications | display set
>
> set groups junos-defaults applications application junos-ftp application-protocol ftp
>
> ...

Please find the snippet below that am using currently to get the config

`from jnpr.junos import Device
    from lxml import etree
    dev = Device(host='xxxx', user='demo', password='demo123', gather_facts=False)
    dev.open()
    cnf = dev.rpc.get_config()
    print etree.tostring(cnf)
    dev.close()`

Please let me know if there is any such method available to get the default application group details.

Many thanks,

Prabir

Answer (score 2):

check if this helps

`dev.rpc.get_config(filter_xml='<groups><name>junos-defaults</name></groups>')`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I wonder why it didn't appear in the get_config() output.